# Frequency domain vs time domain equalization

Tags: digital-communications

It is said that a frequency domain equalizer is equivalent to an infinite length time domain equalizer, why is that?

And if this is the case, why hasn't frequency domain equalization been used earlier?

Has time domain equalization any advantages when compared with frequency domain equalization?

Comment: This article might be helpful. It has  comparison of FDE and TDE. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.utdallas.edu/~aldhahir/fde_final.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjklvvwrvPoAhXrxTgGHVPWDiAQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3T1HJrPBrWP03jMKYlJYT9

Answer (score 0):

Frequency domain equalization requires a certain block structure to be efficient. In OFDM, adding a cyclic prefix to the transmitted block, and using IDFT at the transmitter and DFT at the receiver allows the use of one-tap frequency equalizer. In the time domain, the equalizer length is proportional to the number of channel taps. We can use frequency domain equalization in single carrier systems as well, again with proper block structure, and operations.

Comment: I think OP is perhaps asking why that is. Cyclic prefix removes time dependent multipath effects but it's not obvious how that actually impacts the transfer function of the channel from the equalizers view. But the same could be applied to nonOFDM signals where you don't send again until after the end of the last multipath arrives. I think OFDM has an advantage of maybe isolating channel impairments more, since they could be more localized to one frequency band.